# Why is ‘issused warp per scheduler’ so low in code full with IMAD.WIDE instruction in NVIDIA ？

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, nvidia

I use NVIDIA 2080Ti for test，and my test code is follow

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <cuda.h>

struct item_t {
    uint32_t data[12];
    inline uint32_t& __device__ operator[](size_t i)               { return data[i]; }
    inline const uint32_t& operator[](size_t i) const   { return data[i]; }

};


__global__ void test(const item_t *__restrict__ in, item_t *out, int count) {
    constexpr int n = sizeof(in->data) / sizeof(uint32_t);
    int curTh = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (curTh >= count)
        return;

    item_t a = in[curTh * 2], b = in[curTh * 2 + 1];
    item_t accd[2] = {out[curTh * 2], out[curTh * 2 + 1]};
    auto *acc = (uint32_t *)accd;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            uint32_t bj = b[j];
            for (size_t k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                asm("mad.lo.cc.u32 %0, %2, %3, %0; madc.hi.cc.u32 %1, %2, %3, %1;"
                        : "+r"(acc[k * 2]), "+r"(acc[k * 2 + 1])
                        : "r"(a[k]), "r"(bj));
//                asm("mad.lo.u32 %0, %2, %3, %0;"
//                        : "+r"(acc[k * 2]), "+r"(acc[k * 2 + 1])
//                        : "r"(a[k]), "r"(bj));

            }
        }
    }
    out[curTh*2]   = accd[0];
    out[curTh*2+1] = accd[1];;

}

typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cudaSetDevice(0);
    cudaStream_t stream;
    cudaStreamCreateWithFlags(&stream, cudaStreamNonBlocking);
    int nth = 1;

    if (argc > 1) {
        nth = atoi(argv[1]);
    }

    int NTHREADS = 32;
    printf("nth: %d\n", nth);

    item_t *d_in;
    item_t *d_out;
    cudaMalloc(&d_out, nth * sizeof(*d_out) * 2);
    cudaMalloc(&d_in, nth * sizeof(*d_in) * 2);

    printf("run 10 times\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        auto start = Clock::now();
        test<<<nth/NTHREADS + 1, NTHREADS, 0, stream>>>(d_in, d_out, nth);
        cudaStreamSynchronize(stream);
        printf("use: %02fms\n", (Clock::now() - start) / 1000 / 1000.0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and then

> nvcc -std=c++17 -O0 -g    -arch=sm_75  test.cu  -o test
>
> cuobjdump -sass  test

and then the output of sass code is follow

> ...... ......
>
> ```
>     /*0440*/                   MOV R31, R53 ;                                  /* 0x00000035001f7202 */
>                                                                                /* 0x000fe20000000f00 */
>     /*0450*/                   IMAD.WIDE.U32 R28, R44, R21, R28 ;              /* 0x000000152c1c7225 */
>                                                                                /* 0x000fe200078e001c */
>     /*0460*/                   MOV R53, R51 ;                                  /* 0x0000003300357202 */
>                                                                                /* 0x000fc40000000f00 */
>     /*0470*/                   IADD3 R45, R45, 0x1, RZ ;                       /* 0x000000012d2d7810 */
>                                                                                /* 0x000fe20007ffe0ff */
>     /*0480*/                   IMAD.WIDE.U32 R6, R42, R22, R6 ;                /* 0x000000162a067225 */
>                                                                                /* 0x000fc600078e0006 */
>     /*0490*/                   ISETP.NE.AND P0, PT, R45, 0x2710, PT ;          /* 0x000027102d00780c */
>                                                                                /* 0x000fe20003f05270 */
>     /*04a0*/                   IMAD.WIDE.U32 R28, R44, R20, R28 ;              /* 0x000000142c1c7225 */
>                                                                                /* 0x000fc800078e001c */
>     /*04b0*/                   IMAD.WIDE.U32 R58, R41, R22, R4 ;               /* 0x00000016293a7225 */
>                                                                                /* 0x000fc800078e0004 */
>     /*04c0*/                   IMAD.WIDE.U32 R46, R40, R22, R2 ;               /* 0x00000016282e7225 */
>                                                                                /* 0x000fc800078e0002 */
>     /*04d0*/                   IMAD.WIDE.U32 R32, R43, R21, R8 ;               /* 0x000000152b207225 */
>                                                                                /* 0x000fc800078e0008 */
>     /*04e0*/                   IMAD.WIDE.U32 R4, R42, R21, R6 ;                /* 0x000000152a047225 */
>                                                                                /* 0x000fc800078e0006 */
>     /*04f0*/                   IMAD.WIDE.U32 R8, R44, R19, R28 ;               /* 0x000000132c087225 */
>                                                                                /* 0x000fc800078e001c */
>     /*0500*/                   IMAD.WIDE.U32 R2, R41, R21, R58 ;               /* 0x0000001529027225 */
>                                                                                /* 0x000fc800078e003a */
>     /*0510*/                   IMAD.WIDE.U32 R30, R39, R22, R30 ;              /* 0x00000016271e7225 */
>                                                                                /* 0x000fc800078e001e */
>     /*0520*/                   IMAD.WIDE.U32 R28, R40, R21, R46 ;              /* 0x00000015281c7225 */
>                                                                                /* 0x000fc800078e002e */
>     /*0530*/                   IMAD.WIDE.U32 R6, R43, R20, R32 ;               /* 0x000000142b067225 */
>                                                                                /* 0x000fc800078e0020 */
>     /*0540*/                   IMAD.WIDE.U32 R4, R42, R20, R4 ;                /* 0x000000142a047225 */
>                                                                                /* 0x000fc800078e0004 */
>     /*0550*/                   IMAD.WIDE.U32 R2, R41, R20, R2 ;                /* 0x0000001429027225 */
>                                                                                /* 0x000fc800078e0002 */
>     /*0560*/                   IMAD.WIDE.U32 R30, R39, R21, R30 ;              /* 0x00000015271e7225 */
>                                                                                /* 0x000fc800078e001e */
>     /*0570*/                   IMAD.WIDE.U32 R28, R40, R20, R28 ;              /* 0x00000014281c7225 */
>                                                                                /* 0x000fc800078e001c */
>     /*0580*/                   IMAD.WIDE.U32 R6, R43, R19, R6 ;                /* 0x000000132b067225 */
>                                                                                /* 0x000fc800078e0006 */
>     /*0590*/                   IMAD.WIDE.U32 R4, R42, R19, R4 ;                /* 0x000000132a047225 */
>                                                                                /* 0x000fc800078e0004 */
>     /*05a0*/                   IMAD.WIDE.U32 R2, R41, R19, R2 ;                /* 0x0000001329027225 */
>                                                                                /* 0x000fc800078e0002 */
>     /*05b0*/                   IMAD.WIDE.U32 R30, R39, R20, R30 ;              /* 0x00000014271e7225 */
>                                                                                /* 0x000fc800078e001e */
>     /*05c0*/                   IMAD.WIDE.U32 R28, R40, R19, R28 ;              /* 0x00000013281c7225 */
>                                                                                /* 0x000fc800078e001c */
>     /*05d0*/                   IMAD.WIDE.U32 R8, R44, R18, R8 ;                /* 0x000000122c087225 */
>                                                                                /* 0x000fc800078e0008 */
>     /*05e0*/                   IMAD.WIDE.U32 R6, R43, R18, R6 ;                /* 0x000000122b067225 */ ...... ......
> ```

The ncu-gui run output show follow

[image]

So my question is， Why is 'issused warp per scheduler' so low ？

As I know， In turing architecture， each two cycle can issue one IMAD instruction， And in my code, each instruction is no data dependency in registers， So the value 'issused warp per scheduler' could reach the max value of 0.5

If I use IMAD instead of IMAD.WIDE， in other words I use the follow commented code

```
 //                asm("mad.lo.u32 %0, %2, %3, %0;"
//                        : "+r"(acc[k * 2]), "+r"(acc[k * 2 + 1])
//                        : "r"(a[k]), "r"(bj));
```

and then I got the value 'issused warp per scheduler' close to 0.5
[image]

So why can't I get the value close to 0.5 with IMAD.WIDE instruction?  and Is it possible to do ？

Comment: Check the occupancy. 32 threads per block is too small, even if the number of items is large enough. As you can see in the [Compute Capabilities](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-capabilities), you need about 128 threads per block. Otherwise you run into the limit of resident blocks per SM

Comment: While we're at it, `nth/NTHREADS + 1` isn't how you compute the grid size. If you want integer division rounding up instead of down, write `(nth + NTHREADS - 1) / NTHREADS`

Comment: thanks. I had changed to 128 threads per block, but the issue slot utilization is  still the same

Answer (score 4):

A TU10x SM has 4 sub-partitions (SMSP) that can issue a IMAD instruction every 2 cycles. `IMAD.WIDE` issues (but doesn't increment the issue active counter) the instruction 2 times to perform the lower 32-bit operation and the upper 32-bit operation resulting in a full 64-bit value. The throughput per sub-partition is 1 instruction every 4 cycles.

- `IMAD.{!WIDE, !HI}` can reach a maximum issue slot utilization of .5.
- `IMAD.{WIDE, HI}` can reach a maximum issue slot utilization of .25.

Comment: Why each IMAD.WIDE need 4 cycle ？ As far as I know， each instruction is pipelined. So each instruction should issue one cycle.  two cycle per instruction just because  each sub-partition is 16 core, a half of warp thread number 32

Comment: @sorfkc this is consistent with the [Turing Tuning Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/turing-tuning-guide/index.html): "Each Turing SM includes 4 warp-scheduler units. Each scheduler handles a static set of warps and issues to a dedicated set of arithmetic instruction units. Instructions are performed over two cycles, and the schedulers can issue independent instructions every cycle."

Comment: @Homer512  I know what you mean. I mean, why does the IMAD.WIDE instruction need 4 cycles?   you say ‘Instructions are performed over two cycles’， but why not IMAD.WIDE?

Comment: Because, as stated in the answer, IMAD.WIDE involves ***2*** instruction issue steps.  There is a dependency; the lower 32-bit operation must precede the upper 32-bit operation.  Therefore, 2 issue steps, where each issue requires 2 cycles, and the 2 issues must be sequential, will require 4 cycles total.